# How to load tiff file and save it as a bmp in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I need to convert a TIFF file into PNG file in vc++. How can I load a tiff file and save it as a png using vc++. Is there any third party dll is needed for this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ImageMagick, it contains a C++ API [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php?ImageMagick=bb3027mav5qmfs5i3go0np3176)

Answer (score 0):

You can yse LibTiff (http://www.libtiff.org/). See this post: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/otherformats/article.php/c4933